# libreoffice Convert xlsx to pdf in command line with edge of the table

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xlsx, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to convert the xlsx file to a pdf, but when i do this with the command:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export --outdir . test.xlsx
```

the test.pdf file is well exported, but the table does not have the edge of cell printed.
How i can let the export print the edge of the cell  of the table on the resulting pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, **the only way to do this is remark the edge of cell directly in the file `.xlsx`.**

When you do this the result is printed well.

**There isn't command line for this feature.**